How to read attached object data of points in DXF
I'm reading a DXF with ezdxf module in Python.
Some entities have attribute data, xdata and object data.
I'm able read attribute and xdata, but how to read the attribute data?

dwg = ezdxf.readfile(file)
for layer in dwg.layers:
    entities_on_layer = dwg.modelspace().query( f'INSERT[layer=="{layer.dxf.name}"]')
    # print(layer.dxf.name,len(entities_on_layer))
    for entity in entities_on_layer:
        print(entity.Xdata.data)
        print(entity.attribs)

